# Catching keyPressEvent in multiple selected QGraphicsItems

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a set of QGraphicsItems in a QGraphicsScene in which I've set the drag mode to `RubberBandDrag`. I would like to be able to 'rubber band' select multiple QGraphicsItems and then hit the delete key, which should call keyPressEvent() in all selected items. Unfortunately, keyPressEvent is only being called in at most one of the items.

Is there some flag I can set to allow the keyPressEvent to be propagated to all selected items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign keyPressEvent() to QGraphicsScene (not for QGraphicsItems) and delete all selectedItem with out any problems.